# Redirect to URL in Spring MVC (REST API) with params

Tags: spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc

I have an endpoint in RestController. When  request would be processed , there must performed redirecting to another URL and There need to pass one parameters in redirect URL.

```java
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class RestControllerImpl  {

    @Value("${uri-root}")
    private String uriRoot;

    private final Service service;

    @PostMapping("/api")
    public RedirectView performRequest(@RequestBody Transaction dto) {
       
        service.perform(dto);
       
        String referenceToken = "sldflh@2lhf*shdjkla"

        String urlRedirect = uriRoot + "?token=" + referenceToken;

        return new RedirectView(urlRedirect);
    }
}
```

The code above doesn't work for me.

I was looking for information on stackoverflow, but it suggests either using ModelAndView or RedirectAttributes attributes. But I need endpoint to accept a Post request that would bring data that will be processed in the service layer.

It is not possible to complete this task. Could someone explain how this can work and how such a task can be accomplished ?

Comment: Make a request. A redirect is always a GET and not a POST.

Answer (score 0):

It worked.

```java
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class RestControllerImpl  {

    @Value("${uri-root}")
    private String uriRoot;

    private final Service service;

  @PostMapping("/api")
  public ResponseEntity createClient(@RequestBody Transaction dto)  throws URISyntaxException {
              
        service.perform(dto);
       
        String referenceToken = "sldflh@2lhf*shdjkla"

        String urlRedirect = uriRoot + "?token=" + referenceToken;

        return ResponseEntity.created(new URI(urlRedirect)).build();
    }
}
```